# Is it possible to create GIF with images of difference size?

Tags: gif

I would like to create a simple GIF, consisting of 2 images only:

1. One full white circle (100px x 100px)
2. One half-cirlce (100px x 50px)

The idea is, make it looks like the circle is folded into half from the original.

Now my question is, seems that the GIF software or service i use, only work IF both images are of 'equal size'.

I would like to position the second image (half-circle) at the bottom, as in the image below:

[image]

Is is possible?
Currently I am using ScreenToGif software but there is no luck.

Comment: I think i knew the answer... 
All i need to do, is to add an additional transparency half-center to the second image to make it same size as the 1st. This has nothing to do with GIF software at all

Comment: Exactly. You cannot have two different resolution frames in one gif as far as I know.

Comment: @ElOtmaniAli Ya, when I tried more online services that really seems to be the case. :) Suddenly i found myself dumb asking this. hahaa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's perfectly possible with the GIF image file format. In fact, changing the frame size is one of the ways to optimize the file size of a given GIF file, usually by reducing subsequent frames to contain only the changed parts and combine these with the previous frame.

An application may choose to only allow frames of the same size, of course. For one, this simplifies the user interface because it doesn't need controls to allow the user to position any frames smaller than the resulting image.

For example, the following image is a GIF animation created with 11 full-sized frames, each of them 100x100 pixels. It has a file size of about 2.5 KB.

[image: GIF animation example, unoptimized]

When optimized to contain smaller frames - all of the white squares as 10x10 pixels instead of the 100x100 pixels of the previous image - then the file size goes down to 512 bytes. Your (billable) data transfer for this image has just been reduced by a factor of 5.

[image: GIF animation example, optimized]

The service you are using to create the images may be using such optimizations. To check this, load one of the resulting files into an image editor (for example GIMP) and check the frame sizes there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mind giving an example of the mainstream ways to create a GIF? (which allows 'reduce subsequent frames to contain on the changed parts...)

Comment: Can you please show a sample GIF that has its size being changed over the frames?

Comment: @androiddeveloper you mean like the second GIF image in the answer? Not sure what exactly you are asking for if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher The second GIF has a size that's changing? The web browser doesn't show it. I see a red square with same size for all its frames.

Comment: Look at them in a suitably capable image editor. You will find that the white squares are in much smaller frames compared to the first image.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher Is there an online tool for this? I've tried multiple and didn't find any. All show that it's the same size for each frame

Comment: @androiddeveloper no idea. I've used GIMP to create the images shown in my answer.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher So if I use GIMP, I will be able to see the frames, while some frames have a different size than the others?